# angels of women (same meaning with 'an angel of a woman'?)

Tags: idiomatic-language

> angels of women

Is this idiomatic like 'an angel of a woman'?

The structure itself is the same but only difference is one is in plural and the other in singular.

Comment: Can you please provide some context, a passage in which you have seen each of these forms used. Why do you think there might be a significant difference in meaning? Of-hand I would say tat there was not much difference in meaning.

Comment: angels of / women ? Or angels / of women? Where is the semantically diverging point? Which word or words make(s) the meaning of 'angel-like'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not idiomatic. I suppose it would "women with angelic qualities".  But the usual point of saying, for example "My wife is an angel of a woman" is to emphasise how special one individual is. I suppose you could say, "the [Wrens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women%27s_Royal_Naval_Service) were all angels of women." but that seems odd.

I don't think "angels of women" is ever actually used, and you should probably look for an alternative expression that means the same. One simple choice would be simply to use a metaphor: "The Wrens were all angels".

Comment: ""the Wrens were all angels of women." - not according to my mother's sister, who served in the WRNS from 1940 to 1948.

Comment: Yes... I put that example for the irony!

Answer (score 1):

In English, the typical alternate form for "an angel of a woman" is "an angelic woman". Actually, I suspect the latter to be the more common form.

Comment: 'of a' means '-ic'?